# Not getting additional claims from HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication

Tags: c#, owin, openid-connect, identityserver4, claims

I have a .net form client that uses Owin and Identity Server 4 for authentications and I don't get the additional claims back from 
HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.User. What am I doing wrong?

I am adding the additional claims in my accountController on IDS4 like this:

```
await HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync(user.SubjectId, user.Username, props, additionalClaims.ToArray());
```

On my Client:

```
if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
            {               

                HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(
                    new AuthenticationProperties
                    {
                        RedirectUri = "/Default1.aspx",

                    },                 
                    OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

            }
            else
            {         
                foreach (var claim in HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.User.Claims)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you recieve the claims in the Claims property of this:

```
var claimsIdentity = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
```

This is they way i use it with Owin and cookie authentication and it works flawlessly

Comment: Thank you @Verthosa! I get all of them now :) for some reason I thought I had to get them from HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.User.Claims

Comment: Keep note that the `IPrincipal` may be a `ClaimsPrincipal` which can have multiple `ClaimsIdentity` to fetch the claims from. If the *HttpContext.Current.User* is a `ClaimsPrincipal` you can fetch [all claims](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.claims.claimsprincipal.claims.aspx) from all attached identities.